# VSTS Error SerializationException

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, tfs, iis-7.5

I tried debugging my code in team foundation server and I was receiving an error stating that

```
SerializationException was unhandled by user code and its description is Type is not resolved for member 'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Claims.ClaimsPrincipal,Microsoft.IdentityModel,version=3.5.0.0,Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'. Please see the image for detail error.
```

Sorry, unable to post the image.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Can you give us an idea of what your code was doing?

Comment: Are you trying to serialize your object out to something like JSON or XML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're missing a reference to Microsoft.IdentityModel, so it can't find code to do serialization/deserialization for part of an object.